# How to use text in a cell as reference in Query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell which contains column name in string `"Col2"` and `"Col3"`

```
   A2     B2
------- ------
 Col2    Col3
```

Now I want to pull those string and place it inside my query function to select certain column.

I tried this:-

```
=Query(Sheet2!A1:P1993,"select Col1, "&sheet1!A2:B2&"")
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ampersand is on the wrong side of the quotation mark, try `=Query(Sheet2!A1:P1993,"select Col1, &"sheet1!A2:B2"&")`.

The Query function uses a string `select` statement so what you are really doing is creating that using ampersand to concatenate.